# Debug Azure application without using Azure Storage Emulator

Tags: azure-storage

When debugging in Visual Studio, Azure Storage Emulator always starts automatically, even if my web role configuration points to the storage account credentials (*.blob.core.windows.net) and not the storage emulator. Is there any way to debug and not use the development storage at all?

Answer (score 0):

The emulator starts for your web roles probably. What application is using storage? You can't debug Azure storage. You can only debug an app that is calling storage.

Comment: It is an ASP.NET application that I'm debugging. The problem is that the storage emulator is started automatically when I press F5, even though I specified in the role properties that I wouldn't like to use the development storage but instead, I'm using the Azure storage account (*.blob.core.windows.net) directly.

Comment: Can we debug Worker Role using Azure Storage Emulator?